# How to deal with extra points in exams?

Tags: teaching, grades

If a midterm exam was from 100 points with 5 points bonus(extra points). Then should the total grade be out of 100 or 105? How to deal with cases of students getting above 100? Should their points be used as bonus for the next exams or just throw them out since they don't need them? I feel that since some students would benefit of the 5 points, those who were above 100 should also do, but I am not sure how?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "final grade"? Is the final grade you are referring to really the exact measure of `achieved / available` points? In that case, `achieved / 105` points seems to me like the 5 points are not bonus points at all. If it is *not* the exact quotient, but the quotient is mapped to some discrete scale of grades, there will always be a few points above the last grade that have no effect, and having 105 points, but getting the same grade as with 100 (or maybe even 95 or 90) points doesn't seem unfair. As for using the points for the next exam, this may or may not be ...

Comment: ... allowed by your university, or in general by your jurisdiction. You will have to find out about the rules concerning this and clarify your question (or answer that part for yourself).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper the total points for midterm. So a student get 100 and another get 105, then both will be converted to 100 as the cut off. This is why it seems little not fair.

Comment: And these 100 directly enter a further calculation of a final grade? Sorry to ask so much, but I'm not familiar with that system and instead used to systems where every achieved score is rounded and mapped several times to discrete grade steps before a final grade is reached. Still, if you think it's not fair to cut off the extra 5 points, you'll have to explain in your question how you define "bonus points". In my understanding, those are usually points that are *not required* to reach the *best* grade. If 105 points eventually yields a better result than 100 points, these 5 points ...

Comment: ... are indeed necessary and my definition of bonus points above fails. Maybe you are using a different definition? It would be helpful if you could add that to the question.

Comment: To address your issue of fairness, one way of thinking about it could be that there is a "maximum" score of 100, but multiple ways of achieving it. A student that struggles on deriving equations has a "bonus" chance to make up the points by describing applications of it (and/or vice versa). Of course, if the student is good at both, you could argue they're doing extra work for nothing - or you could argue they're doubly sure of getting full marks

Comment: Yes, 100 points will be converted to 30% of the final score.

Comment: @ThomasLee: And the final score is exact to the decimal? i.e. if I score 99 out of 100 points in that midterm, 29.7% will be added to my final score?

Comment: Yes, to the final score

Comment: I'm really not sure why this question was closed: it seems pretty straight-forward to me.

Comment: @jakebeal I agree, I will guess someone saw "what should I do" and didn't think further.

Comment: What is your goal in having the bonus points? Is it so that a student can still get the maximum score even if they get a question wrong?

Comment: @ThomasLee: So, your final score can have any number of decimal places? It is never rounded at some point?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When I have dealt with extra credit in the past, it was simply retained in the records until the very final accounting of scores at the end of the course.  Thus, if the exam was out of 100 points, it was still considered to be out of 100 points, and some people simply had more than the maximum possible.

When grades were combined together in the final accounting at the end of the course, having a score above the maximum effectively ended up helping compensate for lower scores on other tests (though perhaps not one-to-one, depending on relative weighting).  If a particularly amazing student turned out to get more than the maximum in the class overall, then it wouldn't affect anybody at all: the curve wasn't shifted and they simply got top marks, as they would have if they'd gotten the maximum.

Comment: So if a student scores 105, would you mention 105/100 or just 105 on their exam paper?

Comment: @ThomasLee Probably 105/100.  I might not bother with the denominator if it's spelled out clearly on the exam already, though.

Comment: I would write "96/100 + 9 extra credit", or just "96 + 9" if the denominator is already clear.

Comment: @JeffE: Wouldn't that require that it is clear which points are the bonus points?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Sure, I guess.  OP wrote "from 100 points with 5 points bonus".  I assume that means the 5-point bonus questions were clearly marked as such, since otherwise he would have written "from 105 points".  On the other hand, I sometimes give *individual exam problems* grades like 9+2 to indicate 9/10 points of regular credit plus 2 points of extra credit.

Comment: @JeffE: Possible. All exams with bonus points I've encountered so far did it differently, though; they'd just say something on their title page such as "total points: 100 (+ 5 bonus points)", and the individual maximum scores of the questions (none of which was highlighted as a bonus question) would just add up to 105. After all, what is the meaning of a "bonus question"? When given the choice, is it better to answer a bonus question or a non-bonus question (assuming they yield the same maximum score each)? Is there any difference at all?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper My extra credit points are not the same currency as regular points, but everyone does things differently.

Comment: @JeffE: Sure, if there is a difference, distinguishing them in the sum is completely reasonable.